# To count number of spaces using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question:** I need a solution to find number of empty spaces infront of checkbox inside list tag by using jquery

```
   <li id='list_id'>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="check">good
   </li>
```

Comment: Do the `&nbsp;` entities count? What qualifies as "empty spaces"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var listItem = $('#list_id');

var clone = listItem.clone();

clone.find('*').remove();

matches = clone.html().match(/&nbsp;/g);

alert(matches.length);
```

That will `alert()` the number of `&nbsp;` in the text node of `#list_id`.

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VgBkd/).

Though, if you *only* want leading ones before anything else, try this...

```
var listItem = $('#list_id');

var html = $.trim(listItem.html());

var count = 0;
var match = '&nbsp;';


while (html.substr(0, match.length) === match) {
   count++;
   html = html.substr(count * match.length, (count * match.length) + match.length);
}


alert(count);
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VgBkd/3/).

That will count all `&nbsp;` end-on-end, i.e. *glued* together. If you'd just like to match every one before the opening angle bracket, [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416630/lee) has a [solution available on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/VgBkd/1/).

Comment: ... but it'll count *all* `&nbsp;` s within the `<li>`.  If you only want the ones *before* the `<input ...>`, it'll take a little more parsing to get there.

Comment: @alex: that will strip interior tags but it will still count `&nbsp;` s that come *after* the `<input>`.  How about [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/VgBkd/1/)?  (There's nothing wrong with good old-fashioned string functions)  ;-)

Comment: @Lee See next edit. The version you linked is terser and probably better than my second example :)

Comment: eh... wouldn't it be easier to do `$('#list_id > input').prevAll().text()`? Or....I don't know if that'll grab text nodes or not.

Comment: @Ralph Sounds good, but I got an empty string with `text()` and `null` when I tried it with `html()`.

Comment: @Omeid Herat Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @alex, here we go what is this 'clone.find('*').remove();' for ?

Comment: @Omeid Herat It removes all children from the cloned element.

Comment: @alex, yeah but if you use `find()` is that mather what else is there ?

Comment: @alex: it works, but it's pretty complicated.  Did you see [my simple solution](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/VgBkd/1/) on jsFiddle?  Unless I'm missing something, no looping is necessary - just a simple indexOf and a substring.

Comment: @Omeid Herat I don't understand your question sorry. I removed all children because it seemed the OP wanted to match `&nbsp;` in the direct text node only.

Comment: @Lee I did. Our solutions work slightly different (and I'm not sure what the OP wants exactly). Mine gets `&nbsp;` end on end, whilst your solution will allow other characters between them. I'm sure between them, the OP has their question answered :D

Comment: @Lee I linked to your fiddle in my answer. Let me know if you want to post it as an answer, and I'll modify my edit to point to your answer.

Comment: @got it, you want to get ride of the child nodes which is `<input.....` in this case, i was thinking of the text `good` as a child node too, hahah, anyways thanks for  answer

Comment: @alex: agreed on all points.  Thanks for linking to my fiddle. I don't intend to post an answer of my own (since I got the core of it—the use of `match()`—from you in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

```
var elemntArr=$('#list_id.).html().split("&nbsp;")
```

from the above arrary you can count empty spaces

Comment: `text()` didn't return the literal `&nbsp;` for me.

Comment: @alex , sorry i didn't try in fiddle , do you want me to remove the answer??

Comment: @gov No, feel free to change the `text()` to `html()` :)

Comment: "number of empty spaces" is still ambiguous. doesn't `.text()` return actual spaces? then you could count those instead.

Comment: @Ralph I think we could reasonably infer from the OP's example that the they mean `&nbsp;`. At least I'd be surprised if that wasn't what they wanted.

Comment: i'm sure the OP means to include `&nbsp;` but exclusively? `&nbsp;` can be interlaced with regular spaces without them being compressed, no? just sayin ;) i like to over-complicate things.

Comment: @Ralph hehe. Yeah. Trouble with beginner SO users are their questions are vague or ambiguous - not helpful with computers that do exactly as they are told.